# How to select a DIV if its child has any children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select any divs on a page if a certain child of theirs has any children of its own.

Here's how the structure looks:

```
<div id="ID-SOME_LONG_ID">
    <div class="GK">
        <div id="SOME_LONGID_#1434646398866197"></div>
    </div>                                  
</div>
```

So I want to select all divs with id `ID-SOME_LONG_ID` only if the `GK` DIV has any children.  It may or may not.

`ID-` stays the same and `SOME_LONG_ID` changes with each one.

The other one `SOME_LONG_ID` is the same on as the parent, and after the `#` it's a 16 digit number that is random.

Would using Regex be a good idea to look for them or maybe using jQuery's `.children()` like `$( ".GK" ).children()`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**:has()**](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)**,** [**:empty**](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)**,** and [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('#ID-SOME_LONG_ID:has(.GK:not(:empty))')
```

However, note, `:empty` will fail if you want *real* children without text nodes. In that case you can do

```
$('.GK').filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I may have switched the logic on myself.. what if I want to select only ones  where `GK` doesn't have any children?

Comment: @SS113, remove the :not like `$('#ID-SOME_LONG_ID:has(.GK:empty)')`

Comment: @SS113, if the answer didn't work or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Comment: Thank you so much!  It seems to be selecting the right ones now but I can't see how to hide the selected DIVs by adding `.setAttribute("style","display: none;")`.  I know it's not part of this question so sorry about that.

Comment: @SS113, instead of `.setAttribute("style","display: none;).` try `.hide()` or `.attr("style","display: none;").`

Comment: Thanks! It worked with `.attr()` but it's hiding the `<div id="SOME_LONGID_#1434646398866197"></div>` from my example originally and not the whole `<div id="ID-SOME_LONG_ID">`.  This is what my code looks like now: `var selectDIVS = $('.GK').filter(function() { return $(this).children().length > 0; });`

Comment: @SS113, can you put it up in a fiddle?

Comment: Here's what it's doing: https://jsfiddle.net/vpec3aw6/  it's hiding the GK DIV and its children but not the main one.  I need it to hide everything **if** GK has children.

Comment: @SS113, if you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing help! I had to use a different DIV since there were more nested into each other but ultimately I got it to do what I need!